# How to reciprocate?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

Actually I am coding a Matlab simulation where the AnchorID and SourceID will report to eachother. For example if I take an anchor 30 and source 50 it will collect all the agc values between these anchor and source and calculate rssi_dB and display them.Below mentioned is an example of anchor 30 and source id 50

Note: list of anchors ID's and source ID's are same. for e.g. 30 50 55 58 . These ID are both same for anchor and source.

```
function A30(BlinkSet)
for i=1:length(BlinkSet)

      xAnchorID=30;
      xSourceID=50;
      a=BlinkSet{i}.AnchorID;
      b=BlinkSet{i}.SourceID;
      if xAnchorID==a && xSourceID==b
      xagc=BlinkSet{i}.agc;
      rssi_dB(i)=-(33+xagc*(89-33)/(29-1));
      end
  end
     rssi_dB(rssi_dB==0)=[];
     rssi_dBm=sum(rssi_dB(:))/length(rssi_dB);
     disp([sprintf('The rssi value is %0.0f',rssi_dBm)]);
```

When I call the function in Matlab command window I get the rssi value of the above function.

Also my task is when I reciprocate the Anchor ID and source ID say Anchor as 50 and source as 30 like the function I have mentioned below I get an error which is mentioned after the function below.

```
function A50(BlinkSet)
for i=1:length(BlinkSet)

   xAnchorID=50;
   xSourceID=30;
   a=BlinkSet{i}.AnchorID;
   b=BlinkSet{i}.SourceID;
   if xAnchorID==a && xSourceID==b
   xagc=BlinkSet{i}.agc;
   rssi_dB(i)=-(33+xagc*(89-33)/(29-1));
   end

end
rssi_dB(rssi_dB==0)=[];
   rssi_dBm=sum(rssi_dB(:))/length(rssi_dB);
disp([sprintf('The rssi value is %0.0f',rssi_dBm)]);
```

When I call this function I get an error as

```
??? Undefined function or variable "rssi_dB".

 Error in ==> A50 at 14
 rssi_dB(rssi_dB==0)=[];

 Error in ==> main_reduced at 26
 A50(BlinkSet);
```

In main function I have coded like this,

```
 %A30(BlinkSet);
 A50(BlinkSet);
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both of these functions, you only create the variable `rssi_dB` if execution enters the `if` statement within the loop (i.e., if `xAnchorID==a && xSourceID==b` is at some point true). Clearly, this code is never executed in your `A50` function. Without knowing what is in `BlinkSet` it's a bit difficult to diagnose the exact problem, but this is the cause at least.

As a side note: it's not a good idea to create two separate functions to do this job when their code is almost identical. You should add an input argument to your function that allows it to do the job of both. In this particular case, all that changes is the value of `xAnchorID` and `xSourceID`, so you could just pass these in:

```
function srcToAnchorRssi(BlinkSet, xSourceID, xAnchorID)
    % The rest of the function stays the same!
```

If you want to provide some defaults for these arguments, you can do, e.g.:

```
if nargin < 3 || isempty(xAnchorID), xAnchorID = 50; end
if nargin < 2 || isempty(xSourceID), xSourceID = 30; end
```

It's always a good idea to include an `isempty` in statements of this sort, so that your function supports syntax like `myFunction(myArg1, [], myArg3)`. Also note that the order of the operands to `||` is crucial; if you did `if isempty(theArgument) || nargin < theArgumentNumber` and the user did not pass `theArgument`, then it would error in the `isempty` because `theArgument` would not exist as a local variable. We can get around this by swapping the operands' order because MATLAB is smart enough to know it doesn't have to evaluate the right operand if the left operand is `true` (note that this is also the case in many other programming languages).

Comment: Actually the BlinkSet is a struct which contains around <1561x1 cell>. So inside each cell there are different cells indicating reportings with their AnchorID and sourceID.
Do you mind suggesting an example for the side note you wrote ? it will be helpful !!

Comment: Thank You Wakjah ! out of the blue it does make some sense now ! I will try this !

Comment: @VinithpNair If your question has been answered, you should click the 'accept answer' button so that the question doesn't keep cycling back to the front page (and maybe consider upvoting the answer too).

Comment: @ChrisTaylor thank you for the headsup !!! but upvoting the answers I don't have enough reputations !!